# Prevent a Race Condition using dispatch_sync

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, race-condition

I am having a race condition with a ***NSManagedObjectContext***. I was trying out various ways to prevent this using lock on NSManagedObjectContext. Using dispatch_sync seems to be a better approach as suggested by apple. But I am unable to figure out whether an object(being used under a block which is executed using dispatch_sync) can be saved from being **accessed** by two different threads.

Here is a more clear picture of what I am trying to ask:

```
    [[*Some Singleton class* instance].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

    // After fetching results do something in DB
```

Let's say the above code is passed in a block executed using dispatch_sync like this:

```
    dispatch_sync(someConcurrentQueue, ^{
    [[*Some Singleton class* instance].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
    // After fetching results do something in DB
});
```

Can any other thread access [*Some Singleton class* instance].managedObjectContext before this block is completely executed.

AFAIK it can be accessed. If this is true then, is applying lock on NSManagedObjectContext the only way to prevent this race condition?

Comment: you should have one `NSManagedObjectContext` per thread

Comment: But the problem is even if I have separate NSManagedObjectContext per thread how will that prevent the race condition.

Comment: @EvolGate Race conditions in threading are inevitable. You're trying to mitigate serious exceptions and undefined behavior more than anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always: It depends

`dispatch_sync` (and it's even safer cousin `dispatch_barrier_sync`) cause the queue it's called from to synchronously execute the block.  In doing so, they block the thread.  This makes one case potentially safe: access from the same thread.  What you have to worry about in this scenario is that any reads you do may take place before the block is executed on the queue.  Plan accordingly.

But this is ignoring a huge flaw in your code.  Managed object contexts should **never** be shared across threads, or even dispatched off to a different thread from the one they were created on.  You can fix your concurrent access problems by simply spawning child contexts.

Comment: Yes exactly it is a design flaw, but I will say only one thing that my client gave me this code written by someone else. And the problem is the code is big enough to change the design now. :(...Poor me

Comment: Hmmm.. I cannot prevent any reads to take place before the block is executed. Reason being there is a dispatch_timer running in background that may try to access the object at anytime. I can't prevent that. Please suggest.

Comment: You can fix this easily enough.  Get rid of the singleton (the guy before you should be fired for that alone), and have something more central manage the database and contexts.  You can even provide some convenience that spawns child contexts for you.

Comment: Okay so even if I try to remove the singleton, I am unable to figure out how separate managedObjectContext can save the race condition here. Let's say thread1 accesses the DB and finds one column that needs to be deleted. So before first thread deletes it, other thread accesses this column and it also tries to delete it. How to prevent this

Comment: @EvolGate The way I handled it was forcing everything through a **serial** dispatch queue.  That way your order of operations is guaranteed and no two threads are accessing at once.

Comment: @borrrden But I am using separate threads. What if two serial queues are trying to access the DB.

Comment: Okay, now think about this with multiple contexts.  If Context A spawns Contexts B, and C which are handed off to threads 1 and 2, then you can just tell Context A to merge the changes from both, and let Core Data handle it.  Now, it's up to the merge policy, and you don't have to worry about updating the same context from multiple threads.

Comment: @EvolGate Then don't use two, I used only one.  I had a class dedicated to interacting with CoreData, and no object interacted with the managed object context except for that one.  Every thread added to the same queue in the end.  Obviously, if I only used one thread I wouldn't need any of this safety anyway.

Comment: @CodaFi So will Core Data crash the app if it tries to delete the column which is already deleted by thread 1

Comment: It shouldn't, because the merge policy is smart enough to know when unnecessary changes to the main context have occurred.  It's why we even have Core Data in the first place: To abstract away from all these crashes from ridiculous threading behaviors you're talking about.

Comment: @borrrden Okay think of a scenario in which this common class is being accessed by to separate threads. Thread1 reads the column to be deleted and passes it to the common serial queue. Before thread1 deletes it, thread2 accesses it and it passes this delete call to the serial queue. What will happen if one you try to delete already deleted column. As CodaFi suggests, it won't crash

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks a lot. That would be great. Okay just one last thing....What exactly is this merge policy. Do I need to use some API. I apologize even after using core data for a year now I don't know nothing about this.

Comment: Seriously consider rewriting your entire threading model.  Do you know how completely misguided it is run threaded code like this?  You're looking at a giant game of Russian roulette in the scenarios you're outlining.  Never simply "hand off" chunks of any context to a different thread, never merge updates yourself, and don't think that a serial queue will save you from doing any work at all.  Just gut it and rewrite it; you'll save yourself so much trouble and you won't have to ask all these "what ifs".  Core data provides all you need, so spend some time reading it's documentation.

Comment: @EvolGate So the problem is the order of dispatch then?  A thread might schedule an operation too soon?  Can't help you there, you need to do some work on making sure you do things in the correct order.  If you can insert things in the correct order, serial queues will guarantee that they execute in that order without overlap.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks a lot CodaFi and borrrden. I would really appreciate if you could tell me any blog or any book that's good on threading. I really need to spend more time on this.